# fatal error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, encryption

I have included the file aes.h in the folder where the program is present , but still dont know what else need to do fr this ,any suggestions . Thanks in advance

```
  root@ubuntu:/home/giri/openssl-1.0.1g1/crypto/aes# gcc -Wall aes1.c -lcrypto
  aes1.c:4:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.

  here is the code and ls 
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <openssl/aes.h>

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
   int i;
   int keylength;
   printf("Give a key length [only 128 or 192 or 256!]:\n");
   scanf("%d", &keylength);

   /* generate a key with a given length */
   unsigned char aes_key[keylength];
   memset(aes_key, 0, sizeof(aes_key));
   if (!RAND_bytes(aes_key, keylength))
  {
    exit(-1);
   }
   aes_key[keylength-1] = '\0';

   int inputslength;
   printf("Give an input's length:\n");
   scanf("%d", &inputslength);

   /* generate input with a given length */
   unsigned char aes_input[inputslength+1];
   memset(aes_input, '0', sizeof(aes_input));
   aes_input[inputslength] = '\0';


  root@ubuntu:/home/giri/openssl-1.0.1g1/crypto/aes# ls
  aes1.c     aes_core.c  aes.h       aes_misc.c  aes_x86core.c  Makefile.save
  aes_cbc.c  aes_ctr.c   aes_ige.c   aes_ofb.c   asm            README
  aes_cfb.c  aes_ecb.c   aes_locl.h  aes_wrap.c  Makefile       securiti.c
```

Comment: Could you show us the line with the `#include` statement, as well as an `ls` inside your directory?

Comment: here is the code edited

Comment: Looks like your `gcc` command needs a `-I` flag to point to the location of the openssl header files.

Answer (score 20):

You need to install the openssl development libraries.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: I wonder why they didn't call the package libopenssl instead

Answer (score -1):

for those who are still blocked you can replace this line : '#include <openssl/aes.h>' by that one : '#include "aes.h"' (before ,you must add 'aes.h' in the folder where the program is present)

(replace <openssl/aes.h> by "aes.h")